# Generate a somewhat complex query with joins on subqueries in the FROM clause using zend framework 2 tableGateway

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

I'm trying to generate the following query using Zend Framework 2 tableGateway.

```
SELECT 
dfsstamp, 
dfcstamp, 
df_rstrd_flg, 
dfctid, 
dfname, 
dfloc, 
dfdesc, 
dfcuser, 
dfmuser, 
dfid AS, 
t2.dfdfid, 
ctname, 
cafldnme, 
caid, 
atid, 
atvalue, 
t1.record_count
FROM 
(
    select * from dssdocflp 
    where dfdfid <= 1
) as t2
LEFT JOIN
(
    select dfdfid, count(*) as record_count from dssdocflp
    group by dfdfid having dfdfid > 1
) as t1
on t2.dfid = t1.dfdfid
INNER JOIN dsscfgtpp ON ctid = dfctid 
INNER JOIN dsscfgatp ON cactid = ctid 
INNER JOIN dssattrp ON atcaid = caid AND atdfid = dfid 
WHERE dfdbid = '33' 
ORDER BY dfcstamp DESC, dfid ASC, caseqno ASC
```

Below is what I've gotten so far

```
$select = $this->tableGateway
                   ->getSql()
                   ->select()
                   ->columns(array(
                        'dfsstamp' => new Expression('date(dfsstamp)'),
                        'dfcstamp' => new Expression('date(dfcstamp)'),
                        'df_rstrd_flg',
                        'dfctid',
                        'dfname',
                        'dfloc',
                        'dfdesc',
                        'dfcuser',
                        'dfmuser',
                        'dfid',
                        'dfdfid'
                        //'record_count'
                        ))
                    ->join('dsscfgtpp', 'ctid = dfctid', array('ctname'))
                    ->join('dsscfgatp', 'cactid = ctid', array('cafldnme', 'caid'))
                    ->join('dssattrp', 'atcaid = caid AND atdfid = dfid', array('atid', 'atvalue'))
                    ->where(dfdbid = 33)
                    ->order(array('dfcstamp DESC', 'dfid ASC', 'caseqno'))
```

I just need get the left join with the sub queries to work. I can't figure out which combination of from and join methods I need to put together.   I've been struggling for 3 hours now and though I'd ask for some help.  Any help would greatly be appreciated

Based on the suggestions from @peterpeterson this is the new query I tried

```
 $subselect_t2 = new Select();
    $subselect_t2->from('dssdocflp')
        ->where(array('dfdid <= 1'));

    $subselect_t1 = new Select();
    $subselect_t1->from('dssdocflp')
        ->columns(array(
            'dfdfid',
            'record_count' => new Expression('count(*)')
        ))
        ->group(array('dfdfid'))->having(array('dfdid > 1'));

    $select = $this->tableGateway
                   ->getSql()
                   ->select()
                   ->columns(array(
                        'dfcstamp',
                        'df_rstrd_flg',
                        'dfctid',
                        'dfname',
                        'dfloc',
                        'dfdesc',
                        'dfcuser',
                        'dfmuser',
                        'dfid',
                        'dfdfid',
                        't1.record_count'
                        ))
                    ->from(array('t2' => $subselect_t2))
                    ->join(array('t1' => $subselect_t1), 't2.dfid = t1.dfdid', array(), 'left')
                    ->join('dsscfgtpp', 'ctid = dfctid', array('ctname'))
                    ->join('dsscfgatp', 'cactid = ctid', array('cafldnme', 'caid'))
                    ->join('dssattrp', 'atcaid = caid AND atdfid = dfid', array('atid', 'atvalue'))
                    ->where($this->documentWhereClause->create($searchData))
                    ->order(array('dfcstamp DESC', 'dfid ASC', 'dfdfid DESC', 'caseqno'))
                    ->limit(500);
```

Run I run it I get the following error:

> Since this object was created with a table and/or schema in the
>   constructor, it is read only.

Maybe I'm still not forming the query correctly.  I'm using tableGateway.  Maybe it is not possible to do this kind query via tableGateway?

Answer (score 0):

As per the link bellow, you have to pass the third parameter:

```
$select::JOIN_LEFT
```

Not sure, you may need to save the variable:

```
$select = $this->tableGateway
                   ->getSql()
                   ->select();
```

and then do the joins

[Sql Join zf2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#join)

## Edit

it seems I had missread your questions, here is how you do it:

```
<?php
$subselect = new Select;
$subselect->from('bar')->where->like('y', '%Foo%');
$select = new Select;
$select->from('foo')->join(array('z' => $select39subselect), 'z.foo = bar.id');
```

So basically create another select and then pass it to the join.

Comment: thanks for the answer @peterpeterson but I couldn't get the query to run

Comment: I get the following error: Since this object was created with a table and/or schema in the constructor, it is read only.

Comment: could you update your post with the new code you have created?